# How to implement weighted round robin using c#?

Tags: load-balancing, scheduler

If I have some servers: 192.168.100.1, 192.168.100.2, 192.168.100.3, 192.168.100.4...
and weights of them are: 5, 1, 2, 3

I want to implement load balancing, but how can I implement weighted round robin using C#?

Answer (score 3):

Say you have servers `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. And you have corresponding weights `5`, `1`, `2`, `3`. You can do weighted round robin in the following way:

```
Random rand = new Random(seed);

void processRequest(Request r){

    // assume rand.next() returns a uniformly distributed integer >= 0
    int i = rand.next() % 11; // 11 is sum of weights

    if(i <= 4)      // process r with server a
    else if(i == 5) // process r with server b
    else if(i <= 7) // process r with server c
    else            // process r with server d
}
```

`rand.next() % 11` returns a uniformly distributed integer in the range `[0, 10]` (inclusive). We process the request with server `a` for five of the possible values `[0, 4]`. We process the request with server `b` for only one possible value `5` and so on.

Pay special attention to the particular random method you use and the seed value.

Comment: above code, i understand the number of 4,5,7, but in my website, there servers and weights are configuration, i don't know them in advance.

Comment: Above code assumes the desired weighting is known in advance. So you don't know the desired weighting? How/when do you figure this out?

Comment: @SundayMonday this looks like a solution I've been looking for in a while. In my case I'm suppose to implement this on an .aspx page then redirect the users to the appropriate URL's which I'm pulling from the database. Could you please elaborate more on your answer in more details to fit my situation. Thanx and nice work...I'm using C# too also the server weights i'm getting from the database.

Comment: What is the `Seed` value in this example?

Comment: Also what if you have 2 servers with the same weight?

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic, but this solution produces weighted random selection, not weighted round-robin. In some applications the distinction is meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Random Weighted Select algorithm

```
// returns the index of the chosen one, note that the index starting with 0
static int randomWeightedSelect(List<int> colls) {
    int lucky = rand.Next(1, colls.Sum());
    for (int i = 0; i < colls.Count(); ++i) {
        lucky -= colls[i];
        if (lucky <= 0)
            return i;
    }
    // should never reach here
    return -1;
}
```

Weighted Round Robin Algorithm https://dotnetfiddle.net/71Sft0

```
public class WRRScheduler
{
    // A list of node name/label -> weight
    List<Tuple<string, int>> nodes;
    int maxWeight;
    int step;

    int idx;
    int quantum;

    // for testing purpose
    public static void Main()
    {
        var colls = new List<Tuple<string, int>> {
            Tuple.Create("A", 5), Tuple.Create("B", 1),
            Tuple.Create("C", 7), Tuple.Create("D", 3)
        };
        var s = new WRRScheduler(colls);

        for (int i = 0; i < colls.Sum(e => e.Item2); ++i)
            Console.WriteLine("choose {0}", s.next());
    }

    public WRRScheduler(List<Tuple<string, int>> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;

        this.maxWeight = nodes.Max(e => e.Item2);
        // use gcd as a optimization
        this.step = nodes.Select(e => e.Item2).Aggregate(gcd);

        this.idx = -1;
        this.quantum = 0;
    }

    string next() {
        while (true) {
            this.idx = (this.idx + 1) % this.nodes.Count;
            if (this.idx == 0) {
                // start a new round, decrement current quantum
                this.quantum -= this.step;
                if (this.quantum <= 0) {
                    this.quantum = this.maxWeight;
                }
            }

            // pick the node if its weight greater than current quantum
            if (this.nodes[this.idx].Item2 >= this.quantum) {
                return this.nodes[this.idx].Item1;
            }
        }
    }

    private static int gcd(int a, int b)
    {
        while (a != 0 && b != 0) {
            if (a > b)
                a %= b;
            else
                b %= a;
        }
        return a == 0 ? b : a;
    }
}
```