# Load balancing in weighted round robin using any LB for IIS websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, load-balancing

I have same web application(asp.net) running in two separate servers.

What I'm trying to achieve now is create an aspx page that all users will be directed to initially, On my application I have the ability to retrieve how many users are currently connected to each server. I also added a setting where I set a weight of each server that it can take at a time. Also have the server URL's.

What I need now is a mechanism or a way to split my users among those servers based on the weight of the servers.

I've tried a solution from an archive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494876/how-to-implement-weighted-round-robin-using-c) but I don't seem to understand the solution applied.

Please point me to the right direction or elaborate more on the solution.

Comment: Are your servers running IIS (and what version) or another hosting server?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for, what specifically do you not understand?

Comment: @BerndLinde yes my servers do run IIS version 7, but note I need to do this splitting of users on the webpage not configure it on IIS.

Comment: @beautifulcoder what I'm not understanding is the weighted round robin algorithm to use in C#. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: How it is load balanced, you told you are redirecting to other server upon some condition, anyhow, the receiving server gets all request, so how it is load balanced currently?

Comment: @ArindamNayak currently yes its not balanced the plan is to send the requests to one server and based on the weights set on each it should redirect the users split them equally if weights are set as 50/50.

Comment: Then you should go for some other technique, use HAProxy/Varnish/nginx etc.. as reverse proxy, which will just receive the request and apply round robin logic ( they have inbuilt into that), it will send request to either of IIS server, IIS server will have backnet IP only, it will not be public facing.

Comment: @ArindamNayak could please send me links as to where to get examples or practical implementations. Also is your statement implying that the approach I'm planning to take will not accomplish this?

Comment: @Lord-David - answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with discussion in comments, I found that you need to have a load balancer for IIS websites, you have 2 servers (nodes). You are searching for a solution.

To solve this, you have to take a 3rd server which will take up request and route to rest 2 . The 3rd server is the load balancer, it will act as reverse proxy - it will have public facing IP mapped to your domain. So when end user hits that domain, load balancer (LB) will get request, the LB has config , which algorithm to use. Consider HAProxy, it has tons of algorithm - LRU, RoundRobin, IP hash etc.. Based on that it will transfer request to backend nodes (one of 2 IIS webserver). Note: those nodes don't have to be in public facing IP, because LB's job is to transfer request to internal backnet IP and get response, send to end user. This was , noone is going to get access to actual IIS server's website.

I have presented HAProxy earlier - following is the link - https://arindamnayak1.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/haproxy/

There you can see the alternatives to HAProxy and in reference section , it has some link which shows how to set it up.

Following is a quick link for one of them - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-haproxy-and-load-balancing-concepts

Even SO uses HAProxy - http://brokenhaze.com/blog/2014/03/25/how-stack-exchange-gets-the-most-out-of-haproxy/

Comment: Thank you, I might have not mentioned that the application is hosted on client servers. So im limited to what they have. So that is why Im planning to do this within my application only. Its the only thing im in control of.

Comment: Even in that case, you can use this - adv, you don't have to worry about different algorithms, if you go with your way- still you need a IIS website to take request and load balance - where as with any of LB - take a lighter web server to just load balance - just redirect to client servers.